# Bash getopt does not accept some of the double dash (--) character

Tags: bash, getopt

I got a weird error when using the following `getopt` when passing the `-` character. Here is the example of the code and the output:

```
#!/bin/bash

function _echo()
{
  msg="$1"
  # A sample getopt option with only t as short parameter
  # I put -q to silent error and use output based on getopt return status
  options=$(getopt -q -o t -- "$@")
  retval=$?
  if [ ${retval} -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "${msg} <--[this has error]"
  else
    echo "${msg} <--[this is ok]"
  fi
  echo ""
  eval set -- "${options}"
}

# Calling function _echo() without passing any option (sample):

_echo "--" # OK
_echo "Hello" # OK
_echo "Hello--" # OK
_echo "-" # OK
_echo "---------------" # Error
_echo "---" # Error
_echo "--Hello" #Error
_echo "-Hello" #Error
```

Output:

```
-- <--[this is ok]

Hello <--[this is ok]

Hello-- <--[this is ok]

- <--[this is ok]

--------------- <--[this has error]

--- <--[this has error]

--Hello <--[this has error]

-Hello <--[this has error]
```

You can see that some of the above statements passed to `_echo` function have errors even the strings are quoted ? How do you overcome this problem if you want to pass the long dash character (`-------`) inside the _echo function ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting doesn't matter...there's no difference between calling `_echo --Hello` vs calling `_echo "--Hello"`. In both cases, the `_echo` function receives a single parameter, `--Hello`. Since you only accept the parameter `-t`, anything else that looks like a parameter is going to cause an error.

The correct way of handling this is described in the `getopt` man page:

> Each parameter after a '--' parameter is always interpreted as a
> non-option parameter.  If the environment variable  POSIXLY_CORRECT is
> set,  or if the short option string started with a '+', all remaining
> parameters are interpreted as non-option parameters as soon as the
> first  non-option  parameter is found.

In other  words, if you want to pass in  a parameter like `--Hello`,
you need to call `_echo` like this:

```
_echo -- --Hello
```

The `--` tells getopt that any following parameters should not be interpreted as options, even if they happen to look like one.

So the examples in your script would look  like:

```
_echo "--" # OK
_echo "Hello" # OK
_echo "Hello--" # OK
_echo "-" # OK
_echo -- "---------------" # Error
_echo -- "---" # Error
_echo -- "--Hello" #Error
_echo -- "-Hello" #Error
```

This is a common convention for many command line programs.

---

As you spotted, there were problems with your implementation of `_echo`. Here's a typical structure for parsing options with `getopt`:

```
function _echo()
{
  options=$(getopt -q -o t -- "$@")
  if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "ERROR: incorrect options in $@"
    return 1
  fi

  eval set -- "$options"
  while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
    case $1 in
    (-t)   echo "got -t"
          shift
          ;;

    (--)  shift
          break
          ;;

    (-*)  echo "unknown option: $1"
          return 1
          ;;

    (*)   break
          ;;
    esac
  done

  msg=$1
  echo "message is: $msg"
}

# Calling function _echo() without passing any option (sample):

_echo "--"
_echo "Hello"
_echo "Hello--"
_echo "-"
_echo -- "---------------"
_echo -- "---"
_echo -- "--Hello"
_echo -- "-Hello"
_echo -t -- "-Hello"
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand why. I did not know that `getopt` would care about the quoted strings. Now I'm looking for  a way to make the _echo function handle this error instead of modifying the passing parameters.

Comment: I understand the concept. I accepted the answer without looking at the output. So, when you use `_echo  -- "--Hello" ` it actually did not pass the string --Hello instead the msg only received the argument `--`. So, that means the output is in the second argument. So, do you think I should do conditional checking in _echo or is there a way to suppress this behaviour.

Comment: It did actually pass the string `--Hello`. Your call to getopt is using `"$@"`, which is all the arguments passed to the function. You should only be looking at `$1` after processing all the options.

Comment: Yes, I knew I could do `$*` to get all strings but is this the only way that we can do in getopts? Do they have hidden option to overcome this. I feel like this is a bad practice to pass `--` in order to solve this. Looking for a regex condition that can handle this, if msg contains some invalid string like only accept this `(^-.*)$` then we remove the single or double hypens and re-add the string.

Comment: See my update, which includes a proper implementation of `_echo`.

Comment: Ok, now I feel very stupid, that actually I can do another check like what you did there!, I did that before. I was too much depending on the sample file which I forgot my getopt implementation is not completed with `while loop`. and `case` conditional Thank you so much.